PHP with error_reporting E_ALL ignores <?php}?> while it should error
I had made a booboo in a script by writing <?php}?> instead of <?php }?>.
My local Xampp server did not complain and happily served the file, while my actual server served a blank page and generated an error log (as would be expected, as <?php should be following by a space or line break).
This made me wonder why my local PHP is simply ignoring it.
I have compared both servers.
My local server runs PHP 8.0.28 and remote server 8.0.30.
Both servers have error reporting level E_ALL.
PHP file header has error_reporting(E_ALL);
Local server php.ini error settings:
error_reporting=E_ALL
display_errors=On
display_startup_errors=On
log_errors=On

Yet, it still doesn't show an error (or notice, for that matter).
When testing with a simple undefined variable to test the error level, it throws a notice - so the error reporting works fine. Also tested by echo error_reporting();, which echos 32767 (E_ALL).
Why is my local PHP not throwing an error?

Is the PHP version the same on both the local server and the actual server?

@NasserHajlawi The question says the local server is 8.0.28 and remote is 8.0.30.

@Barmar :D :D I read the question again after your comment one more time, but I couldn't find the version code. I used CTRL+F to search for it. :D I think I need some sleep.

I get a syntax error in both 8.2.7 and 7.4.33.

It might be worth inspecting the runtime values of the other settings using ini_get. Also, remember to only test this in the browser, not on the CLI
